# JAVA Printing issues using printf

Tags: java

I have some issues with printing my code. I want my result to be aligned neatly but it isn't like that. It would be very grateful if someone could help me with the issue.

my code is as follows :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int j=1 ; j<=31;j++) {
        System.out.printf("%10d",j);
        if(j%7==0) {
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

the result I get to see on my screen as belows

[image]

Comment: try: System.out.printf("%-10s",j);

Comment: @user202729 i posted it now as an anwer

Comment: For OP: It would be better for you if you explain more what do you expect.What is 'neat'?

Comment: @user202729 neatly means accurately

Comment: @Rcordoval (1) I'm telling OP not you (2) That's not precise enough. Both answers are assuming OP want the output left-aligned, but what if OP want it to be right/center/sth-else aligned? Unclear.

Comment: actually it doesn't matter whether it is left/right/center aligned . i just want it to be aligned.I am sorry if I did not make clear enough  and  I've tried all the advice but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct. But you should use MONOSPACED (fixed width) font like Courier or Lucida Console in your terminal / console:

- you use not monospaced font in your OS terminal
- or you use not monospaced font in the  console of your IDE
- or you forward your output to file that you view in some editor again with not monospaced font
- or something similar with not monospaced font

Comment: Using a fixed width font is the correct advice. However, you are mixing things up in your answer. True type refers to a font technology (font format) and can be used for fixed width and variable width fonts alike. MONOTYPE is a company providing fonts and tools.

Comment: Thank you so much I don't really understand what monotype font or true type is but changing a font solved my problem.

Comment: @Henry : Yes, I meant monospaced, not monotype :) :) But you are right about TTF, I vote your comment up :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Formatting Numeric Print Output](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

> Format specifiers begin with a percent sign (%) and end with a
>   converter. The converter is a character indicating the type of
>   argument to be formatted. In between the percent sign (%) and the
>   converter you can have optional flags and specifiers

In this case:

1. `%` is format syntax mandatory prefix.
2. `-` is the flag for Left-justified.
3. `10` means ten characters in width, with leading zeroes as necessary.
4. `d`, A decimal integer.

So your main method should be:

```
public class Tst {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        for(int j=1 ; j<=31;j++) {
            System.out.printf("%-10d",j);
            if(j%7==0) {
                System.out.println();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Giving the resulting output:

[image]

Comment: thank for your help but the result looks the same as before